# Removing Heavy Rust from Very Old Carbon Steel Carving Knife on the Cheap

Tags: physical-chemistry

I am trying to remove heavy rust from a carbon steel 10-inch carving knife. Mothers Polish did not get rid of much of the rust. I turned to vinegar soaking and scrubbing: At first it took off a good bit of the rust leaving visible residue in the bottom of a glass carafe. With a lot rust left I turned to vinegar and salt (see below). I have been soaking the knife using this solution in the 1-quart glass carafe for three or four days. Every day I pull out the knife and scrub it vigorously with a wire brush. Lots of black stuff comes off on a paper towel but there is still a lot of stubborn rust. When I take the knife out of the carafe the knife is blacker then when I put it in. After a vigorous wiping an alligator-like pattern remains on both sides.

I am using the same solution daily without changing it save for topping off the carafe. Also there seems to more chemical activity going on at the top of carafe than at the bottom, for some reason: is there an explanation of the phenomena?

If the rust is indeed being dissolved slowly I am wondering if the solution is loosing potency? Is the stoichiometry changing as the rust is being removed? Would changing the solution daily/ frequently help speed this process? Would frequent stirring help uniform the gradient? Is there a better method using household products?

I do not want to resort to expensive OTC cleaners or high-end sandpapers. Oh! FYI: pun intended-I am many decades rusty in Organic and Physical Chemistry.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Source of the idea: Hunker....Fill a large container made of a non-reactive material, such as plastic or glass, with 1 gallon of distilled white vinegar. Add 1 cup of table salt and stir the mixture to combine. The salt will increase the potency of the acid in the vinegar, making it even more effective. Use 1/2 gallon of vinegar with 1/2 cup of salt for smaller objects

Comment: Here's an idea: just ditch the rusty thing and buy new. BTW if you'd try too hard you could dissolve also metal - all in all, not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reasonably remove rust by dissolving it; mechanically remove it with wire brush , sand blast, etc. Then "covert" the small remaining amount with phosphoric acid containing solution such as Navel Jelly. Presumable converting it to iron phosphate. Coat the surface with something like oil as it can oxidize again fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off to use a bucket (or any other container which does not conduct electricity, like you already do), and to fill it with some of luke warm water, add kitchen salt (needn't be saturated).  Vinegar *alone* can not reverse the reaction of rust in iron, but if you use a charge carrier *plus* a metal less noble than iron, you may remove quite some of the rust.

Find some Al foil which will serve as galvanic/[sacrifical anode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_anode), scratch it with a metal brush, then wrap the iron in question with this foil and put both into the water such that both metals are in contact with each other and both Al and iron equally are in nice contact with the water/salt solution, too.  It may take hours, it may take more than one «bath»; while there is no guarantee that all rust is removed this way, at least a significant portion is going to be removed with much less manual labor. During this process, slowly, the foil is eaten away.

Answer (score 0):

First, read [my answer here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/129108/will-galvanic-corrosion-happen-on-a-ring-made-of-gold-and-bronze/129116#129116) where I cite the electrochemistry background. The latter include source links to galvanic corrosion and, in particular, in the current instance, a classic case of pit corrosion.

Stop long-term soaking, as this in the presence of salts and an H+ together with dissolved oxygen will just further promote the slowly evolving electrochemistry.

I, personally, ignored stake-knives left in a sink (water and oxygen exposure) that were used to cut a mango. The sticky mango juice, rich in Ascorbic acid (Vitamin C) is apparently particularly notorious for promoting pit corrosion.

Never have completely removed the stains, so do not have high expectation here,